# Why I can browse microsoft.com throw my browser but cannot telnet it?

Tags: http, tcp, telnet

I can browse microsoft.com using my browser, but I cannot connect to its 80 port using `telent`, why.

```
# host microsoft.com
microsoft.com has address 64.4.11.37
microsoft.com has address 65.55.58.201

# telnet microsoft.com 80
Trying 65.55.58.201...
Trying 64.4.11.37...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Are you using telnet from the same host you are browsing microsoft.com from?

Comment: Did it work with IP address instead of hostname? See where you get redirected and use that IP.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your firewall. It happens often that on Windows for example connections to some outgoing ports or to external network are blocked for most apps unless you allow it. There should be no difference otherwise: both your browser and telnet use tcp and the same destination host+port.

Comment: I am using Linux, and after I drop all the rules from iptables, I still cannot connect to it. :-(

Comment: I tried on Linux and it worked. Try to use IP instead of hostname. Maybe you get a redirect like @scotth noted.

Comment: Firewall/proxy may certainly be involved - perhaps blocking the hosts for microsoft.com but allowing the route to the CDNs Microsoft uses for www.microsoft.com - which may be different for the OP depending on his location or the origination of his dns request...

Answer (score 0):

When I open http://microsoft.com in a browser I get redirected to http://**www**.microsoft.com which is a different host.

```
$ host microsoft.com
microsoft.com has address 65.55.58.201
microsoft.com has address 64.4.11.37

$ host www.microsoft.com
www.microsoft.com is an alias for toggle.www.ms.akadns.net.
toggle.www.ms.akadns.net is an alias for g.www.ms.akadns.net.
g.www.ms.akadns.net is an alias for lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.
lb1.www.ms.akadns.net has address 64.4.11.42
```

Try opening your telnet to `www.microsoft.com 80` or the IP address you get from `host www.microsoft.com` instead and see how that works.